# Event handler access modifier MFC vs C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, mfc

I've recently been developing both MFC and C# Windows Forms applications and I've noticed a difference between the access modifiers on auto-generated event handlers.

In MFC

```
public:
afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
```

In C# Win Forms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So my question is, why are the event handlers declared public in MFC, I would have though the C# way is technically better as it promotes encapsulation (which is perhaps why it was changed).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I did MFC...

Ultimately the way that C# and MFC dispatch messages is different, and equally the two are not just different languages, but entirely different platforms - so it's not really correct to say that one is 'better' than the other, *especially* simply because of the visibility of an event handling method.  There's nothing stopping you from changing the visibility of a C# handler, in fact in some cases you might need to in order to fake-invoke an event (although there are other more proper architecural ways of achieving the same thing).

Generally a form's controls and their events are it's own business by default and that makes perfect sense.  Equally, another clue as to C#'s default `private` stance is in the signature of the handlers - they all expect a sender and event data (note that MFC doesn't) - if the underlying control is private, then there's no reason to have it public or protected because an external caller cannot provide the correct arguments to the event handler.

In that respect, it's right that the handler be private.

Comment: The answer is good, but I want to add that the event handlers in MFC don't need to be public, they are public for default. All the calls happen through pointers to these methods (the MESSAGE_MAP).

Comment: Léo - yeah I did know that a function pointer table is used - and I thought that visibility didn't matter (but I didn't want to say that as it's been a while); I do remember taking advantage of the default public as you could then wire another window's handler to a message, which was cool for complex UI